# Exp-resso Store - custom fields in control panel

Tags: expresso-store

Is it possible to add a custom order field to the Orders page in the control panel of Exp:resso Store? If it is possible, how is it done?

Edit: I need to include the customers company name not a custom field.

Comment: Are you requiring users to be registered? It seems that this information would be attached to the customer, not the order.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you have checked the Order fields in Store Settings in the CP?
Do you have a Billing_company and shipping_company field?  If so, these are easily mapped to your existing member fields.  You would need to create any custom member fields first (e.g. billing_company).